# URL to be used in Text Field

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a url `'http://example.com'` as one column value in a table. I want to use this column value in my page as page item text box. Furthermore, if I click on that link, it should navigate to http://example.com.

When I tried to retrieve it from database as

```
Select attachment  --my column name, in which url is stored
into :P_40_ATTACHMENT 
FROM xxtable 
 where sno=1
```

I was able to get the values `example.com` but I am unable to find the hyperlink.

Comment: Does the return string from the database return `http://example.com` or is it just returning `example.com`? is hard to understand what you are trying to do? also are you doing something like `<a href="db_returned_value"> click here </a> ` or are you just displaying as text ?

Comment: Exactly; `<a href=...` is what you need. Don't forget to set column's "Escape special characters" property to "No".

Comment: Hi Miguel, I have saved the text                                                   http://example.com                                                                                                 in the one of fields/columns (attachment) in the table xxtable.                    database return http://example.com but while i try to click on the http://example.com, it is not providing any link.

Comment: Hello Miguel, a text field is a form entry component. It allows you to enter data to be saved. It will never be a clickable url. For something to be clickable on a web page, you need to have an ```"<a href"``` tag as described above and that is not possible on a text field. You could add post text or pre text with a value of ```<a href=&P_40_ATTACHMENT.>&P_40_ATTACHMENT.</a>``` and that would be clickable but if you change the value in your text field ,that url will not contain the new value until you have submitted your form

Comment: Can I use button instead of Text box ?

Comment: You can use a button to redirect a user to an url. I suggest you play around with this. Once you get to know apex better it'll be more obvious to you what the best option is.